# efficient way to process multiple files in parallel with different arguments and using python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have multiple CSV files that needs to be processed with pandas and other libraries, to later concatenate after processing each one. Thus far, I am processing this in a very inefficient way: launching several terminals, each one running the same script but with different parameters.

In order to keep this manageable, I compiled a list of the files to be processed, and divided the list in 10 "chunks", each listing several files to be processed sequentially.

```
splits = 10
master_list = [file1, file2, fil3, ...filen]
all_chunks = np.array_split(master_list, splits)

chunk_dict = {}
for i in np.arange(splits):
    chunk_dict[i] = list(all_chunks[i])

for i in range(splits):
    name = str(i) + "_list.pkl"
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(chunk_dict[i], f)
```

Then, I launch a terminal and run:

```
python myscript.py 0
```

Which runs has code to read 0_list.pkl and process the files in that list. Then I repeat this process launching additional terminals, but referring to the remaining "chunks" (ie, python myscript.py 1, python myscript.py 2, etc.). The code does what I want, but, is there a more efficient way to do this using python **multiprocessing** or any other library?

Since each "chunk" has hundreds of files, and the computations I do for each file are heavy, the code still takes some time to process a "chunk". I could speed it up by having more "chunks", but that also means manually launching more terminals with the script (or writing a bash script, but I believe it will still run each chunk sequentially).

Also, is there a way to determine the optimal number of "chunks" for my processor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Pool` can handle this. By default, the pool will create one process per CPU on your machine. Since they all will spend some time waiting on the disk to read the files, its a good way to mostly commit your machine. Its something you can tweak if either CPU usage or disk usage makes your machine unresponsive to other programs.

The pool divides work into chunks much like your example, but in the case of heavy processing on potentially variable sized files, a chunksize of 1 can avoid you wating for the tall-pole process to complete.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def do_the_work(filename):
    pass

master_list = [file1, file2, fil3, ...filen]
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(do_the_work, master_list, chunksize=1)
```

Comment: So the solution above bypasses the creation of my pickled sub lists? I'll try it, looks promising.

Comment: Yes, kind of. The pool pickles master_list much like you do but its set up an interprocess pipe to send the file names to the subprocesses. The subprocesses get a chunk, process, get another chunk, process etc... until they've worked through the entire queue.

Comment: They also send the result of the worker function back to the parent. You may be able to send the processed dataframes back to the parent to be concatentated where I just have the "results" placeholder. That works well if you've got plenty of memory, but writing the interim data to disk to be read later makes sense in large data situations. Its may also be nice to have the interim data on disk so that its generation can be optionally skipped if its still up to date.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I have 128GB RAM, so I should not have problems.